# Video appears green-ish when adjusting gamma & saturation with ffmpeg (eq) but NOT with mpv

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors, mpv, gamma

I'm using `mpv` as a video player and `ffmpeg` as a video encoder.

I have an original video which I am re-encoding with `ffmpeg`'s [`eq` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#eq) to increase gamma & saturation. Before I do this, I use `mpv` gamma & saturation increase option to have a rough idea of what I would like (with <kbd>5</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd> & <kbd>7</kbd>-<kbd>8</kbd> keyboard keys).

Problem: when I use `ffmpeg` with, say `-vf 'eq=gamma=1.2:saturation=1.2'`, no matter what settings I tried, **the result looks a little green-ish** compared to what I get with `mpv` (the white wall is not so white anymore, but slightly "tainted" with a green hue).

**How can I correct gamma & saturation with `ffmpeg` without having this change in colours?**

Comment: What if you left out the saturation increase?

Comment: I can think of cases where simple re-encoding creates green tint. Please post steps for reproducing the issue. For example: Link for specific YouTube video to download, and complete FFmpeg command line. Post an example of specific frame that shows the problem (compare between `mpv` and `ffmpeg`).